# Webpacker load error (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, metismenu

Trying to get a (what should be) simple module to work: [metisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu)

However, unfortunately I'm failing in doing so, apparently something in my Webpacker setup because when loading my page I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function`

There is an issue in loading the module in `application.js`. The module is being loaded in `vendor/assets/javascripts/app.js`

- I have jQuery correctly installed
- the following snippet into the head section makes it work (but this is without the use of Webpaker):

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/metismenu"></script>
```

.
I've created a github branch. Please help! https://github.com/henkjanwils/metisMenu-error

Comment: How will the code in your application.js file even know what `$(..)` means given the transpiling etc.: don't you need to install JQuery via Webpacker and add it to your `environment.js` file for it to work? I suppose using a CDN will work fine if you add a separate script tag AFTER the script tags which gets the jquery via the CDN.

Comment: Thanks! I've been wondering this as well. I actually also installed jQuery in `aplication.js` but the weird thing is (I debugged it) that removing one of each JS includes throws back the error.

Comment: Have you also installed metis menu via yarn? That way you can remove the script tags entirely

Comment: Hi BKSpurgeon, thanks again. I did install the metisMenu through yarn. The `package.json` confirms this. Leaving the `<script>` tags out, gives me the error, whilst putting the `script` tags solves the problem. But the latter is not a clean solution since it is without Webpacker